# Can I buy, insure and register a car as a foreigner in Nevada in 1 day?

Tags: usa, canada, driving, automobiles, insurance

I'm planning to fly to Las Vegas on holiday and drive to Toronto in a used car. I live in the UK and am unfamiliar with licensing laws in Nevada (and the rest of the US!) - though from what I understand the car would need insuring and registering before I could drive it. These are my questions:

1. Do I simply need to ensure my full UK driving licence is valid for the insurance I buy?
2. Can insurance be purchased instantly online? What is sufficient for proving I have it when registering the car?
3. How do I register the car and can I do it online?
4. Can insurance and registration be handled on the same day?
5. Is there anything I need to be aware of when driving between various states and Canada? These are the states I plan to visit:

   - Nevada
   - Arizona
   - Utah
   - Colorado
   - Kansas
   - Missouri
   - Arkansas
   - Tennessee
   - Kentucky
   - Indiana
   - Illinois
   - Michigan

Just to point out in advance, I'm well aware that I could hire a car, but that's not an answer to my questions.

Thanks!

Comment: My answer would have been "Look here", but that won't suffice. http://www.carinsurance.com/kb/can-I-buy-and-insure-a-car-with-an-international-license.aspx